# PR2 install ros-hydro-pr2-desktop as in tutorial

Tags: ros-hydro, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just trying to install hydro to the PR2. When I type   `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pr2-desktop` I have the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-pr2-desktop
```

It's not able to locate the package. As explained in http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/PR2/hydro, the package source `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main` is one of my source.d files, nonetheless it doesn't detect the package. Any ideas???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152261/pr2-install-ros-hydro-pr2-desktop-as-in-tutorial/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-12-09**:
I recently apt-got it from http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu. Could you retry? Check this http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-hydro-pr2-desktop/ to see if you are also able to see the debs.

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-12-11**:
sorry, I won't be able to test it with the robot until mid-January :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Siligon,

this will be available soon as all of the pr2-metapackages are building in the shadow-fixed repo. Give it another month or two, and the PR2 will be fully available in Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-12-05**:
Thank you for the answer, I haven't been working with the robot in a long time. Some people in the lab are working right now with it. I just posted another [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/198964/pr2-indigo-will-it-be-ever-a-thing/).

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-12-08**:
I got back to them in that thread :) Thanks Silgon.